# Git checkout: get the same behavior as SVN revert

Tags: git, git-checkout

I noticed that SVN revert doesn't EXACTLY behave the same way as GIT checkout...:

**SVN case:**
If I have a SVN remote repository that I checkout on my computer, and make modifications on a file locally. While I do this, someone commits new changes on that same file on the server.

Now I want to revert my changes on my local repository. I do

```
svn revert [file]
```

And this gives me the file in the exact same state as the one I had on my computer when I checked out the remot repository.

**GIT case:**
Now With GIT. I clone a remote repository, do some changes on a file, someone pushes some commits that affects that same file, and I want to do

```
git checkout -- file
```

This is gonna give me the version of the file modified by *that someone mentioned earlier*, not the file I cloned at the beginning of this user story.

Now, I guess I could do:

```
git checkout [commit number of the remote version I cloned] -- file
```

But I find it "tedious / vexing", knowing that I just want to revert my file to the local version of my repository.

So my question is:
Is there a way to specifically checkout a file to the version I had on my local repository when I last pulled the remote repository? something like:

```
git checkout local -- file
```

?
Thanks in advance for your precious comments & answers =)

Comment: Have you tried to do `git checkout -- file` before writing the question? Because it will checkout appropriate version of file, unless you did `git pull` before, which you didn't because you needed to resolve conflict in `file` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, what you need to remember is that git is configured (usually) for the "master" branch to *track* the remote/upstream master.

What you probably want to do is create a local branch right after you clone the repository: `git checkout -b my_branch` — and do your work here, so its unaffected by changes upstream, but these changes will still be pulled into your local `master` branch.

You can then `git rebase` your changes onto the current master, when you're ready, at your convenience.